# How to run the same function for different IDs separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate multiple progress/loading bars. The code below works how I want it to and I could just copy and paste then replace the ID name but that seems unnecessarily long. What's an efficient way to use my jquery code with different types of IDs (eg: #bar-x, #bar-y, #bar-z)? I've tried separating with commas like below

```
$(function() {
  var $stat = $('#bar-x, #bar-y, #bar-z');

  $stat.waypoint(function() {
    $stat.css({
    animation: "loading 1s linear",
    opacity: "1"
    });
  }, { offset: '95%' });
});
```

but then it runs all the animations at the same time when the first object reaches the requirement instead of when each individual object reaches the said requirement.

Comment: You could just use one class and put it on each element instead of a handful of unique IDs. `var $stat = $('.myClass');`

Comment: Add the id as an argument?

Comment: @TylerRoper: Well... I interpret it as OP wants to run the animations on different times. Then using a class would not work. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Nah I re-read the question, I think you're correct. I didn't realize the timing concern. That said, I believe the classes could still work as a collection, which OP could step through sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just wrap it in a function and use it like this

```
function myAnimation(selector){
  selector.waypoint(function() {
    selector.css({
      animation: "loading 1s linear",
      opacity: "1"
    });
  }, { offset: '95%' });
}

myAnimation($('#bar-y'));
```

This way you'd be able to call on your animation with any kind of selector repeatedly and re-usable fashion.

I'd suggest reading up on some functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the other answers aren't acknowledging the queue-ing aspect of your question so I figured I'd touch on that. In such a case, you could loop through the elements and attach the animation one second apart to each one.

Using the code below, all of the `setTimeout()`s will be instantiated at the same time, however the first will be for `0ms`, the second `1000ms`, the third `2000ms`, so on and so forth.

```
var $stat = $('.bar');  //add class "bar" to each item you want to be included
var msDelay = 1000;

$stat.each(function(index) {
  setTimeout(() => loadNext($(this)), msDelay * index);
});

function loadNext($elem) {
  $elem.waypoint(function() {
    $elem.css({
      animation: "loading 1s linear",
      opacity: "1"
    });
  }, {
    offset: '95%'
  });
};
```

### Demo

```js
var $stat = $('.bar');
var msDelay = 1000;

$stat.each(function(index) {
  setTimeout(() => loadNext($(this)), msDelay * index);
});

function loadNext($elem) {
  $elem.css({ opacity: "1" });
};
```

```css
.bar {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Waypoints, it seems your issue comes from using the `$stat` object inside your callback function:

```
...
    $stat.css({
    animation: "loading 1s linear",
    opacity: "1"
    });
...
```

When the requirement for one of the waypoints is reached, it will call your .css animation on ALL of the elements that `$stat` contains.  What you need is to make it a bit more dynamic and use `this.element` in place of `$stat` (or similar, depending on the version of Waypoints you're using).

Answer (score -2):

```
var divId = "#bar-x";


function animate (var divId)
{

 var $stat = $(divId);

  $stat.waypoint(function() {
    $stat.css({
    animation: "loading 1s linear",
    opacity: "1"
    });
  }, { offset: '95%' });

}
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong in the original code and how you're fixing it.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.